# How can I use a non-default Output object when running a Symfony command?

Tags: php, symfony

[Symfony provides other classes that implement `OutputInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Output). How can I provide instances of these classes - ideally from the command line or other config options - to a command?

My current workaround for using different Output objects is to immediately reassign `$output` to the preferred object like so:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\NullOutput;

class DebugCommand extends Command
{
    protected function Configure()
    {
        $this->setName('AppBundle:DebugCommand');

    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output = new NullOutput();
        $output->writeln('Done!');
    }
}
```

But this feels sloppy. It would make much more sense to simply provide the intended object as a parameter to `DebugCommand::execute()`. Plus, If I decided *I did* want the output - I would have to modify the code to get the intended behavior.

How can I achieve this properly?

**EDIT:**

My hope is that it will be possible to set a default for each command. This would be helpful because I could create a new class that implements `OutputInterface` that would post output to, say, my team's Slack channel. But a different command might need to post to a *different* team's Slack channel. Being able to customize the output object for each command would be helpful as each command might affect different teams.

Comment: Are you using the framework or just the console component?

Comment: @Laoneo The whole framework - but if there's an answer that address just using the component, I'd be pretty interested to see that too.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the framework, then you do have similar code in your console script:

```
$application = new Application($kernel);
$application->setDefaultCommand('default');
$application->run($input);
```

what you can do now is to add a second argumen to the run function, like:

```
$application->run($input, new NullOutput());
```

**EDIT:**

How to do it per command needs a new class which extends the Application class:

```
class SlackOutputApplication extends Application{
    protected function doRunCommand(Command $command, InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        if ($command->getName() == 'foo') {
            $output = new SlackOutput('channelname');
        }
        parent::doRunCommand($command, $input, $output);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but doing this will affect *all* of my commands application wide - is it possible to fine tune the output for each command?

Comment: I guess then you need to overwrite the application class and overwrite the `doRunCommand`.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - but all it appears to be doing is pushing the bad practice up the call stack, which IMO is less practical than reassigning it within the command. This way, a new dev would have to know to look inside `SlackOutputApplication` to determine why they can't view the output on the command line. Plus, I'd probably opt to put Slack URLs/channel names/whatever in a parameter within the container. It doesn't look like  `Output` instances are supposed to know of the container, where the command can (if extending `ContainerAwareCommand`). I might have to add a feature request

Comment: For sure I would inject something into the command constructor which knows already to which channel to write to. But I tried to answer your question with a simple example. What you make out of it is up to you.